# options for returning distinct values across an inner join

Tags: sql, join, distinct

I have two tables.

Table A contains UserID, UserName

Table B contains ID, FK_UserID, ClientName

I need to return a list of distinct A.UserName where A.Username exists in table B and has at least one ClientName attached to them, but in my query, only look at distinct B.ClientName.

My thoughts were:

```
Select Distinct A.UserName from A as A
Inner Join B as B
on A.UserID = B.FK_UserID
```

But that only distincts on table A

My next thought was:

```
Select Distinct Username from A
where UserID In 
(
Select FK_UserID, distinct ClientName from B)
```

I was told that there is a way to do a distinct on both tables in the join, because if table A is 300 rows, and table B is 3 BILLION rows, my original query is going to take awhile.

The person specifically wants me to use an inner join...

Comment: What do you mean by "in my query, only look at distict B.ClientName"?  You're not returning ClientName in the results are you?  What does that mean in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query is:

```
Select Distinct A.UserName
from A as A Inner Join
     B as B
     on A.UserID = B.FK_UserID;
```

This can be a problem, if there are many matches in `b`.  Using `in` isn't quite the right solution.  Instead, use `exists`:

```
select a.UserName
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where b.fk_UserID = a.UserId
             )
```

Then, be sure that you have an index on `b(fk_UserId)`.

This should do about 300 lookups in the index.  That should be quite fast.

My advice for the person who told you to use the inner join:  Write a special version for that person.  For the many minutes or hours that it takes to run, let other people use the faster version using `exists`.

Comment: That's another way, but what about using an inner join? That's what they're asking for and I have to figure out how...

Comment: @MichaelHarness . . . If each id in table `a` has lots of matches in table `b`, then an inner join could take a long time indeed.  Why do you have someone telling you how to write queries (and why do they seem to be wrong)?

Comment: I don't know if they are just testing me, or if this is what they really want. It was a question posed to me today at work by my boss and I haven't been able to find anything relating to it on the internet. I actually have a second unrelated question I will be asking shortly after I do some research from the same person.

Comment: @MichaelHarness . . . A `join` is fine with the same index on `b` and few (up to dozens of) matches per id in `a`.  If you have lots (thousands or more), then a lot of extra time is going to be spent handling the `distinct`.  That is why `exists` is better.